# RadRibbonWindow is not loading application icon from embedded resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

Recently I have changed my WPF application Root window from Window to RadRibbonWindow and this RadRibbonwindow is not loading application Icon from embedded resources. What do I need to do, to make RabRibbonWindow load an icon "ico" from resources automatically? My all other Windows are loading Icon from embedded resources automatically.

Answer (score 0):

in your header:

```
        navigation:RadWindowInteropHelper.Icon="icon.ico"
```

from this example https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/wpf/window/details/how-to-use-radwindow-as-main-window

and the file icon.ico is in the root folder.